# "Tuple" Object Does Not Support Item Assignment, Test-Based RPG

Tags: python

As a separate part of the same RPG, I'm having issues attacking enemies. The function do_damage takes the name/value(health) from the enemy_dict list and computes damage done.

```
def do_damage(self, enemy):
    damage = min(
        max(randint(0, self.health) - randint(0, self.enemy[1]), 0), self.enemy[1])
    self.enemy[1] = self.enemy[1] - damage
    if damage == 0:
        print "The %s evades %s's attack." % (self.enemy[0], self.name)
    else:
        print "%s hurts the %s! -%dhp" % (self.name, self.enemy[0], damage)
    return enemy[1] <= 0
```

self.enemy is assigned like so:

```
self.enemy = random.choice(enemy_dict)
```

as a part of the explore function, which, when called, provides a chance to encounter an enemy.

The attack function, when called by the player, calls the do_damage function.

```
def attack(self):
    if self.state != 'fight':
        print"%s swings wildly at nothing." % self.name
    else:
        if self.do_damage(self.enemy[1]):
            print "%s slaughters %s!" % (self.name, self.enemy[0])
            self.enemy = None
            self.state = 'normal'
            eloot = randint(0,25)
            self.loot = self.loot + eloot
            qxp = randint(0,30)
            self.xp = qxp + self.xp
            print "You find %d gold on the corpse." %(eloot)
            stimp = randint(0,4)
            if stimp == 0:
                self.stim = self.stim + 1
                print "You find a potion!"
            else:
            self.enemy_attacks()
def enemy_attacks(self):
    if self.enemy[0].do_damage(self): print "%s was disemboweled by %s!" % (self.name, self.enemy[0])
```

The attack function is a part of the Player class while do_damage is part of the Character class, which is called in the Player class.

For reference, here's the enemy_dict list:

```
enemy_dict = [
    ("sprite", 5),
    ("thief", 10)
]
```

How do I allow the player to attack an enemy, with what I've got?

Comment: why not `enemy_dict = {"sprite": 5, "thief": 10}` ?

Comment: So... what's the problem with the code you have now?

Comment: Yes, why call it a dict if it's not a dict?

Comment: For some reason having an actual dict is resulting in a syntax error, so rather than change everything I hope to make this work. The problem is somewhere I've apparently tried to assign an item to a tuple, thus the attack function doesn't work.

Comment: @Velcrode Well, a line number would help...

Comment: a line `stimp = (0,4)` looks suspicious, shouldn't it be `stimp = randint(0,4)` ?

Comment: So far what I have supplies the enemy's name and health successfully, so I don't think my method of listing the enemies is flawed, just a bit unorthodox (which I suppose is flawed, as far as convention is taken as the way things must be).

Comment: @nio Yes, good catch. Accidentally deleted it

Comment: Whenever you get an exception, post it in your question; welcome to SO :)

Comment: Can you describe how `self.enemy` is assigned ?

Comment: I'm surprised you're not asking about the `AttributeError` you're going to get when you try to perform the `keys()` method on a `list` which has no such method.

Comment: So far the keys() method isn't ever called, it just runs the data from the list. I realize that's not going to work, but that's another hill to climb.

Comment: That's not a hill to climb; it's a semantic error. I'm writing an answer addressing these things at the moment - give me a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're taking one of the things from the `enemy_dict` list and you're passing it as an argument to your player character's `__init__` and assigning it to `self.enemy`. The problem is that you are trying to change the second value in that tuple (which I assume is the HP of the enemy). You cannot assign anything to the values inside tuples - tuples are immutable.

```
>>> t = (1,2,3)
>>> t[1] = 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

So, you need to use a `list` instead of a `tuple`, a la `enemy_dict = [["sprite", 5], ...]`.

You use some other worrisome language in your post, though.

> Enemy is a class, where self.enemy is assigned (I assume)

What do you mean by "I assume?" Did you not write this class? Also, you do not assign anything to the `enemy` attribute of this class in your constructor, so you obviously are not assigning `self.enemy` in the `Enemy` class.

Furthermore, you are trying to call `.keys()` and `.values()` on `enemy_dict` which is a list. It doesn't have those methods. If it were a `dict`, you would be trying to assign something like `['sprite', 'thief']` to the enemy's name anyway, and likewise `[5, 10]` to the health.

You also are not passing `enemy_dict` as an argument to `Enemy`'s `__init__`. You should, if you wrote this class yourself, change it to be:

```
def __init__(self, name, health):
    self.name = name
    self.health = values
```

And call it like so: `an_enemy = Enemy(enemy_dict[0][0], enemy_dict[0][1])`. This is assuming you are not going to change `enemy_dict`, which you *really* should do. Might I suggest:

```
enemy_dict = {
    "sprite": 5,
    "thief": 10
}
```

Then you can get the health by saying `enemy_dict[name]`. You have to choose a name, though - you can make sure you are choosing a valid name by saying `if name in enemy_dict.keys()`. You can now say `an_enemy = Enemy(name, enemy_dict[name])`.

If you want to implement "random encounters," it's as easy as using the [`random`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module. You already use `random.choice` - so this shouldn't be too hard. Just use `enemy_dict.keys()` instead if you are using a dictionary.

```
self.enemy = random.choice(enemy_dict.keys())
```

The above code makes the `enemy` attribute be the name, which is the key for that dictionary. To get the health, of course, it's `enemy_dict[self.enemy]`.

You should note that if you modify the health in the `enemy_dict`, that will affect every object's perception of that enemy's health. If your `enemy_dict` represents unique entities, that's fine - but if you wanted to have more than one `"sprite"`, you could use the `enemy_dict` as a type of lookup table from which to get random types of enemies to fight, and you would do better to use something like this:

```
self.enemy_name = random.choice(enemy_dict.keys())
self.enemy_health = enemy_dict[self.enemy_name]
```

Then, modify `enemy_health` from within your player character's class.

Comment: self.enemy is defined in the explore function in the Player class, as self.enemy = random.choice(enemy_dict). Sorry for my incorrect clarification earlier.

Comment: Writing enemy_dict as an actual dict results in a syntax error, for some reason specifically the last }.

Comment: If I use a dictionary, what do I replace in the explore function to encounter an enemy? It returns the "instancemethod object is unsubscriptable" error.

Comment: @Velcrode I apologize about the syntax error - I accidentally typed an extra comma. I'll edit that. And I'll answer your second question too.

Comment: nitpick: `if name in enemy_dict` is more idiomatic than `if name in enemy_dict.keys()`.

Comment: @HenryKeiter Definitely. Both achieve the same thing, but the latter is more explicit - which you'd think is more Pythonic ("explicit is better than implicit") but then you see people generally recommending the former. Do whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of the `Enemy` class does not make sense to me, because it means that one instance of `Enemy` has all the enemy names and health defined in it. I would have written this way:

```
class Enemy(Character):
    def __init__(self, name, health):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
```

But even now, the code you wrote does not fit with what I understand: you call `self.do_damage()` with the parameter `enemy=self.enemy[1]`. According to the `do_damage` method, this object is a list where `enemy[0]` is the name of the enemy, and `enemy[1]` is his health. I would have written respectively `enemy.name` and `enemy.health`:

```
def do_damage(self, enemy):
    damage = min(max(randint(0, self.health) - randint(0, self.enemy.health), 0), self.enemy.health)
    self.enemy.health = self.enemy.health - damage
    if damage == 0:
        print "The %s evades %s's attack." % (self.enemy.name, self.name)
    else:
        print "%s hurts the %s! -%dhp" % (self.name, self.enemy.name, damage)
    return enemy.health <= 0
```

and I would have call `do_damage` differently:

```
def attack(self):
    if self.state != 'fight':
        print"%s swings wildly at nothing." % self.name
    else:
        # we suppose that self.enemy is an instance of the Enemy class
        # initialized somewhere else
        if self.do_damage(self.enemy):
            print "%s slaughters %s!" % (self.name, self.enemy.name)
            self.enemy = None
            self.state = 'normal'
            eloot = randint(0,25)
            self.loot = self.loot + eloot
            qxp = randint(0,30)
            self.xp = qxp + self.xp
            print "You find %d gold on the corpse." %(eloot)
            stimp = randint(0,4)
            if stimp == 0:
                self.stim = self.stim + 1
                print "You find a potion!"
        else:
              self.enemy_attacks()

def enemy_attacks(self):
    if self.enemy.do_damage(self):
        print "%s was disemboweled by %s!" % (self.name, self.enemy.name)
```

Comment: Implementing the changes to do_damage you suggested results in the error "'list' object has no attribute 'health'".

Comment: You added below that `self.enemy = random.choice(enemy_dict)`. Is it possible to change this to: `self.enemy = Enemy(*random.choice(enemy_dict))` ?